# Is it compulsory to have a master's degree in computer science for research jobs?

Tags: phd, research-process, graduate-admissions

I hold a bachelor's in computer applications. I have got my bachelor's degree from India. Now I want to get a job in research institutes or labs at Europe, USA or India. Will I need higher education like master's or PhD? Money does not matter to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could aim at **technical universities** (in Germany and Switzerland, they are called "*Fachhochschulen*", Universities of Applied Sciences). Their focus is more on applied research and teaching. I worked 2 years there as a researcher without a MS in CS.

Answer (score 10):

It is highly unlikely that you'd get a permanent research position in CS with a bachelor's degree. It's also unlikely (though not impossible) that you'd get one with an MS degree (for example, it might be possible to enter an organization after an MS, and then move internally into their research wing). The most common path to getting a research job at an institute is after a Ph.D.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to target a PhD student position. As a rule, this requires master degree.

PhD is not required and will actually decrease your chances significantly, as  (following unwritten or written rules) you cannot become a PhD student second time, if you already have one degree. You must then aim to the post doctoral position that has much more requirements.

It is not very difficult to get a PhD student position in Europe, and it is not complex to get a few post doctoral positions afterwards, but getting a permanent position in science later is much more problematic.

Comment: i didnt even done my masters because i find it not useful ... but i got good job

Comment: because i was too lazy in my graduation and scored just 76% i dont think it will get me admission in any good university